# Launch a single activity in a new task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app that runs a service (audio player) in the background and displays an ongoing notification while it is run. When the user clicks the notification, I'd like to open the player activity without it showing up in the recents list and without bringing the rest of the app to front, so when the user presses the back button they go directly to the app they were using previously, regardless of everything. I tried three different ways and none of them worked well.

1. Start an intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If there is an existing task, it's brought to the front. When the user presses the back button, the player activity finishes and reveals the previous activity in the said task instead of going back to the app that had been in foreground the moment the notification was clicked.
2. Start an intent with the following flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`. The existing task isn't brought to the front and the back button works as expected. However, after this activity finishes, the app disappears from the recents list completely. The only way to get it back is to start it from the launcher icon which brings that existing task to the foreground as if opened from recents.
3. Start an intent with the following flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`. The activity starts in a new task, but said task replaces the main one in the recents list. Adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` makes it behave exactly as in previous case.

Is there any proper way to do such navigation, or should I give up trying and just make it bring an entire existing task to the front with the player activity launched on top of it, as in case 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the proper way to do this: add the `taskAffinity` attribute to your `<activity>` in the manifest. This way, it won't interfere at all with how the rest of the app displays in recents, exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Is it convenience for u to declare the launchMode to "singleInstance" inside this Activity Tag in the Manifest File? I think that may help u.but i am not sure.U can try

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try launchmode as a tag for your notificationActivity in your manifest;

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try new document-centric API:

[Adding Tasks to the Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html#adding)